# Planet Orbital locations based on year / month. (table?)

Tags: classical-mechanics, astronomy, planets

I am finalizing an Orrery that used Arduino to move planets into their respective orbital position based on the year and month from a users input. I am looking for a table or database that has the location of each planet as represented in a concentric plane. For example January 2018, Earth was 9.81° from 0 (arbitrary I know, got to start somewhere).

[image: Planet Angle]

[image: Orrery nearing completion]

Right now I am using an extremely crude formula to calculate the planets location angle based on the orbital period and a fixed date (Jan 2018). Of course this will result in gross errors when extrapolating out to dates more than a few years forward or backwards (orbits are elliptical). What I would like to do, is have a table with each planets location based on January of their respective year. I will program the system to lookup the value for each planet and move them to their respective position. Now I imagine the mathematics for producing this is WELL outside of my expertise and mathematical prowess.

[Orrery in motion](https://www.facebook.com/ZeroDegreeC/videos/1783022565118403/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The concept you're looking for is that of an [**ephemeris**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeris): from Wikipedia,

> an ephemeris (plural: ephemerides) gives the positions of naturally occurring astronomical objects as well as artificial satellites in the sky at a given time or times.

There are a large number of published ephemerides, and they're easy to find once you use that search term (and, particularly, if you look for *heliocentric* planetary ephemerides). If you're looking for a good place to start with, I understand the [JPL Horizons](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/?horizons) system is a solid starting ground, and it seems to be sufficiently well documented.

To be honest, though, given the look of your device, I seriously doubt that using hard-coded year-by-year data will significantly increase its accuracy as compared to just hardcoded rotation rates. As you point out, planetary orbits are elliptical - but your device does not actually implement this from the look of it, and neither does it get the planetary orbital radii correct (which is a hard problem, because of the wide range of scales, but something I'd class as more important than the mild ellipticities and the various [elliptical anomalies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eccentric_anomaly)). But ultimately, it's your project, and it's your opinions on what's important that count.

Comment: Thank you very much. Knowing the correct search term is more than half the battle!  I know that accuracy is out the window with this type of device, its a very basic machine that is obviously not more than a desktop trinket. I will dig into the data available for ephemeris that pertains to my project. Thank you again.